# Handling WSAENETDOWN

Tags: winapi, error-handling, winsock

I'm new to Winsock programming and I'm trying to learn how to use asynchronous sockets with WSAEventSelect(). I'm a bit unsure on how to handle a WSAENETDOWN error.

What exactly happens when I get a WSAENETDOWN error? Are my sockets and event objects automatically destroyed? What sort of cleanup do I need to do? What is the proper way of handling a WSAENETDOWN error if I'd like to try to reconnect? Is it ok to call connect() again, should I close and recreate my sockets and event objects, or should I call WSACleanup() and start over from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

`WSAENETDOWN` means that on this socket a network error occured and sending and receiving data is not possible anymore. To handle this error you should close this one socket. There is no need to close other sockets or `WASCleanup` as other sockets can still be functionable (think about a computer with two network cards where one network is down but the other still functions). The sockets and events are not destroyed automatically.